# Change timezone in Google Search Console

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

Is there any way to change timezone in Google Search Console? or google account?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! Not that I can find. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your time zone in Calendar > Settings > Time Zone. That's the only place in Google's account where you can do it.

[image]

Regarding Google Search Console, there is no such option and doubts it'll be. By default UTC -08:00 is the timezone used in California and used by Googlebot and crawl-related events.

In addition, you can use the [International Targeting tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/i18n?hl=en) to specify a country where your potential users are. That might help to adjust GSC's timezone.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With regards to [how the data is reported on in Google Search console](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1308626?hl=en) the help docs state:

> Search Console timestamps data according to **Pacific Daylight Time**.

PDT is UTC-07:00. ("Pacific Standard Time" (PST) is UTC-08:00)

However, if you hover over the little help icon in GSC it states that "All dates recorded and displayed in Pacific Time Zone (PT)", which implies the times will change between PDT and PST throughout the year depending on when daylight savings time changes?

[image: Time Zone reported in GSC]

This does not seem to be configurable in GSC, unlike Google Analytics where this can be configured in *view settings*.

Comment: You're right. You can't change the timezone for the Search Console reports.